# What's weka's kmeans output (WCSS) mean?

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, k-means

I was using weka to do K-means clustering, when i tried a small set and found 
the within cluster sum of squared errors(WCSS) value was not what i thought to be.

I thought WCSS was the sum of squared distance of all elements to it's cluster center,
but the value was not right:

for example:
the data set was:

```
3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
4.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0
4.0, 1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
3.0, 2.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0
3.0, 2.0, 6.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0
4.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
4.0, 1.0, 8.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
3.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0
```

and the cluster(only one) center was `3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1`:

the weka output WCSS was 39, but according to my understanding, it should be `133`.
I know i must be wrong about what WCSS means, could anyone tell me about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what is reported is the WCSS after the attribute values have been normalized.  Unfortunately, I was not able to replicate your result.

However, using your dataset with SimpleKMeans (k=1), I got the following results:

- Before normalizing attribute values, WCSS is 26.4375
- After normalizing attribute values, WCSS is 26.4375

This [source](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/mobasher/classes/ect584/weka/k-means.html) also indicates that Weka's K-means algorithm automatically normalizes the attribute values.

Comment: I set the number of clusters to one, but I realized I added his cluster center as a data point!  I am updating the WCSS values now, although, it is still not his result.

Comment: Normalising seems to be it: http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/questions-about-clustering-td3805.html Shame we can't get the same numbers

Comment: our results are different because i treat these data (all) as nominal,

Comment: In that case the nominal attributes are converted to binary. I do not believe you should expect the result to be the same as your numerical calculation.  If you provide your data example in .arff format, we could try to confirm this (without knowing the levels of your nominal data this would be a tall order)!

Comment: Thank you, here is my .arff file:

Answer (score 0):

@relation cancer

@attribute a1{1,2,3,4,5,6}

@attribute a2{0,1,2}

@attribute a3{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

@attribute a4{0,1,2,3,4,5,8}

@attribute a5{0,1}

@attribute a6{0,1,2}

@attribute a7{0,1}

@attribute a8{0,1,2,3,4}

@attribute a9{0,1}

@attribute label{0,1}

@data

3,2,3,0,0,2,1,0,1,1

4,1,3,0,1,0,1,4,1,0

4,1,7,0,1,1,0,1,1,1

3,2,7,0,0,2,1,1,0,0

3,2,6,1,0,1,0,2,1,1

4,2,5,1,1,1,1,0,0,0

4,1,8,0,1,2,0,0,1,0

3,2,2,0,1,1,0,0,1,0

3,2,0,0,1,1,1,3,1,0

Comment: K-means is really meant for *continuous* values, not for categorical data (even if you binary encode your categories or give them numeric labels). Because the **mean does not make much sense anymore**.